# How can i bubble up an array in a recursive python function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic-programming

I am learning dynamic programming and a video i am watching shows a solution to a problem in JS like this:

[image]

I am trying to figure out how to write this solution in Python, i have made my recursive function like this:

```
def howSum(nums: List[int], target: int):

    if target == 0:
        return []
    elif target < 0:
        return None

    for num in nums:
        rem = target - num
        res = howSum(nums, rem)

        if res:
            res.append(num)
            return res

    return None

print(howSum([2,3,5], 8))
```

But it my function returns `None` instad of returning the array `[2,2,2,2]`.

Is there something i am doing wrong to translate this function from JS to Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty arrays are falsy in Python, so `if res` should be `if res is not None` (in order to match the corresponding condition in JS).

Comment: @DYZ The condition should pass if `res` is a list (empty or not).

Comment: wow thanks i was stuck on this for so long last night, i could've sworn i tried that